# creating a templete having grouping of html features

Tags: html, css

i create a template in which i use a span which pseudo classes try to make grouping features but it is getting pixelates when i change the screen size can you plzzz help me out in this problem. I will show the image how it should be looked [image]

only issue is in responsivness

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/t93v93cn/

code is below

HTML

```
   <div class="grouping-container">
        <span class="groupBadge"><h4>Group1</h4></span>
        <div class="headingContainer">
            <h1>Heading 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
        </div>
        <div class="heading-container">
            <h1>Heading 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.grouping-container{
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: 30px auto;
    padding: 15px 15px 50px 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ccc;
}
.headingContainer,.heading-container{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 85%;
    margin: 5px auto;
    background: rgba(35, 122, 197, 0.4);
    padding: 5px 25px 50px 25px
}
.headingContainer p,.heading-container p{
    font-size: 25px;
}
.headingContainer:before{
    content: "";
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 25px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34px;
    margin-top: -6px;

}
.heading-container:before{
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    padding: 0 24px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 33px;
    bottom: 55px;
}
.groupBadge{
width: 108px;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 18px 120px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #7ecaca;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 43%;
    left: -217px;
}
.groupBadge:before{
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 105px;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    left: 100%;
}
.groupBadge:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 105px;
    color: red;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 7px;
}
.groupBadge h4{
    margin-top: -10px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    padding-right: 36px;
}
```

Comment: Instead of px use em, by default the ratio is 16px to 1em

Comment: @zer00ne have you hard about grouping in html. if you don't mind can you please update the fiddle that will be appericiated

Comment: No, grouping doesn't sound like anything specifically associated with HTML or CSS AFAIK. There's too much code it's a redundant but simple task to convert px to em. Wherever there is a px measurement, divide that number by 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Here is a flexible , responsive approach Using pseudo css elements.**

**This is how the structure is working:**

> The horizontal lines(Top and Bottom)-

Using the  div `grouping-container`  I am making the **top and bottom horizontal green line** with `after and before pseudo` element.

```
.grouping-container:after {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.grouping-container:before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

> The vertical Line-

For the vertical line I have wrapped the elements in more more div with FauxElementline  class which using before pseudo css generates the green vertical line.

```
.FauxElementline:before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```css
.grouping-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 15px 15px 50px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #ccc;
}

.headingContainer,
.heading-container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 85%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  background: rgba(35, 122, 197, 0.4);
  padding: 5px 25px 50px 25px
}

.headingContainer p,
.heading-container p {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.groupBadge {
  width: 50px;
  height: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #7ecaca;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -90px;
  left: -65px;
}

.groupBadge h4 {
  margin-top: 75px;
  transform: rotate(270deg)
}

.FauxElementline:before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

.grouping-container:after {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}

.grouping-container:before {
  content: '';
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  left: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grouping-container">
  <div class="FauxElementline">


    <span class="groupBadge"><h4>Group1</h4></span>
    <div class="headingContainer">
      <h1>Heading 1</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</p>
    </div>
    <div class="heading-container">
      <h1>Heading 2</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what part of it is not working?? @MujtabaHussainBhat

Comment: Updated my answer with explanation